# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `doctordata` (
  `Id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
  `AltPhone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RegDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pincode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HospitalName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Validate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Document` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsOnline` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `DepId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
  UNIQUE KEY `Phone` (`Phone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The complete error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
  `AltPhone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) DEFAULT N' at line 5
```

Comment: I'm not sure that DEFAULT NOT NULL makes much sense; and let's hope two doctors don't share the same address (and telephone)

Comment: Also store dates as a `date` type, not a `varchar`. Putting `DEFAULT NULL` in your structure is redundant. The default value of a column is `NULL` if nothing is specified.

Comment: BTW: The manual that is referred to in the error message is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: I hopen no one makes a typing error when entering the `HospitalName` for a patient....  (and that no Hospital decides to change it's name)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `doctordata` (
  `Id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `AltPhone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RegDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pincode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HospitalName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Validate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Document` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsOnline` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `DepId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Phone` (`Phone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

You made several typos. "DEFAULT NOT NULL" should be only "NOT NULL". Also you missed "," after "PRIMARY KEY" line.

Comment: And your datatypes or not correct, and `DEFAULT NULL` is pretty useless (see comment on question), and there are more datatypes than `VARCHAR()`

Comment: I just formatted the syntax to make it work. What datatype would be used, I hope questioner can decide for himself.